# Hide/Show on left side using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to hide/show a div on click. I want the div to go left to hide when I want it to hide. I have this. But the div goes up to hide. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6fK8G/3/)

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#showmenu').click( function() {
       var hidden = $('.sidebarmenu').data('hidden');
       $('#showmenu').text(hidden ? 'Show Menu' : 'Hide Menu');
       if ( hidden ) {
           $('.sidebarmenu').css({
               position: 'absolute',
               left: -200000
           });
       } else {
           $('.sidebarmenu').css({
               position: '',
               left: 0
           });
       }
       $('.sidebarmenu,.image').data("hidden", !hidden);
    });
});
```

And this is my HTML

```
 <button id="showmenu" type="button">Show menu</button>
 <div class="sidebarmenu" style="position: absolute; left: -200000px">
     This should go left
 </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "go left"?

Comment: Now, it is going up when hide. I want to fade it to left when the user selects hide.

Comment: It's physically going left. If you say, for example, set the -200000 to 20, you can see that it's moving properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `animate()` to show that it moves left

Edit:

If you want show the div initially:

Html:

```
<button id="showmenu" type="button">Hide menu</button>
<div class="sidebarmenu">
     This should go left
</div>
```

JS:

```
if(hidden){
        $('.sidebarmenu').animate({
            left: '0px'
        },500)
    } else {
        $('.sidebarmenu').animate({
            left: '-200px'
        },500)
```

css:

```
.sidebarmenu{
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px
}
    }
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2v5J/1/)

Comment: what should I do to make the div visible on load?

Comment: @Anusha Honey i have set the left position to -200px by default in css once look the css i have removed inline css

Comment: I want the div to appear initially. Then the button says "Hide menu". When the user clicks on the button, div should hide and the butto n should say "Show menu"

Comment: @Anusha Honey See my Edit

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you use the `css` property, the action will be immediate. If you want to see it "animate" itself (and thus see the left movement), you should use the `animate` function with the same set of CSS properties.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
        var hidden = $('.sidebarmenu').data('hidden');
        $('#showmenu').text(hidden ? 'Show Menu' : 'Hide Menu');
        if(hidden){
            $('.sidebarmenu').animate({
                position: 'absolute',
                left: -500
            }, 500);
        } else {
            $('.sidebarmenu').animate({
                position: 'relative',
                left: 0
            }, 500);
        }
        $('.sidebarmenu,.image').data("hidden", !hidden);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the fiddle you have included jQuery UI, in that case you can use `toggle` an jQuery UI easings, without gone grazy using negative left, but only using display block-none.

Updated using displaying state inestead of attribute `hidden`.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
        var hidden = $('.sidebarmenu').is(':visible');
        $('#showmenu').text(hidden ? 'Show Menu' : 'Hide Menu');

        $(".sidebarmenu").toggle("slide", {direction:'left'});

    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W5Wmw/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var status = 0;
$("#mobileMenuButton").click (function (){
    if (status == 0){
        $('#element').css ({'left': 0, 'transition' : '0.3s'})
        status = 1
    } else if (status == 1){ 
        $('#element').css ({'left': '-355px', 'transition' : '0.3s'})
        status = 0
    }
```

css: `#element{ 
    left: -355px
}`